# Constructing Brownian bridge from 0 to T

Tags: r

I'm trying to simulate a Brownian bridge from Wiener process, but struggling with code.

Here is what i'm trying to do in math form:

```
B(t) = W (t) − tW (1)
```

It is important, that W(T) = 0, so that the process is pinned at the origin at both t=0 and t=T (should start and end with B(t)=B(T)= 0

Here  I'm defining Wiener process:

```
n <- 1000 
T <- 1 
delta <- T/n 
t <- seq(0,T, delta) 
set.seed(17) 
W1 <- cumsum(c(0,rnorm(n, 0, 1) * sqrt(delta))) 
plot(t, W1 ,type = 'l',
     xlab = 't', ylab = 'W(t)', xlim = c(0, T + delta))
```

Here I'm trying to build the Brownian bridge, but getting wrong result:

```
B <- W1 - t * W1[T]   # The Brownian bridge from (0,0) to (1,target)
plot(times, B, type="l")
```

I expect `B[1] == B[1001]` to be [TRUE] and equal to 0, but in my case B[1001] is not equal to 0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please format the code in your post.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163047/simulating-a-brownian-excursion-using-a-brownian-bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just one issue - in the definition of `B`. Instead you want

```
B <- W1 - t * W1[n + 1]
```

since the indexing `n + 1` (i.e., choosing the last element corresponding to t = 1) refers to `W1` as a vector rather than a process. Then indeed

```
B[1]
# [1] 0
B[1001]
# [1] 0
```

as expected. Note also though that using `t` and `T` as variable names is not advisable as both of them already have important roles; see `?t` and `?T`.